# K-means clustering interpretation

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 3 cluster pair plot with "Av. Mon. Hrs","Sat. Lvl","Last Eval", and found a matrix graph by below code.

```
library("ggplot2") # Expanded plotting functionality over "lattice" package
x<-cbind(HR_left$average_montly_hours,HR_left$satisfaction_level,HR_left$last_evaluation)
kmfit<-kmeans(x,3,nstart=25) 
# Find the best 3 clusters using 25 random sets of (distinct) rows in x as initial centres.
pairs(x,col=(kmfit$cluster), labels=c("Av. Mon. Hrs","Sat. Lvl","Last Eval."))
```

It says

- Cluster 1: The pairs plot characterised this cluster as working low
  average monthly hours of employees, middle satisfaction range and a
  low last evaluation.
- Cluster 2: From the pairs plot, this cluster is
  characterised by high monthly hours, very low satisfaction and high
  evaluation.
- Cluster 3: From the pairs plot, this cluster is
  characterised by high monthly hours, high satisfaction and high
  evaluation.

But I don't understand the pairplot graphs about how they interpretative of these three findings.

```
library(readr)
HR_comma_sep <- read_csv("https://stluc.manta.uqcloud.net/mdatascience/public/datasets/HumanResourceAnalytics/HR_comma_sep.csv")
HR_left<-HR_comma_sep[HR_comma_sep$left==1,]

library("ggplot2") # Expanded plotting functionality over "lattice" package 

 x<-cbind(HR_left$average_montly_hours,HR_left$satisfaction_level,HR_left$last_evaluation) 
 kmfit<-kmeans(x,3,nstart=25) 
 # Find the best 3 clusters using 25 random sets of (distinct) rows in x as initial centres. 

 pairs(x,col= (kmfit$cluster),labels=c("Av. Mon. Hrs","Sat. Lvl","Last Eval."))
```

Comment: Please provide sample dataset.

Comment: library(readr)
HR_comma_sep <- read_csv("https://stluc.manta.uqcloud.net/mdatascience/public/datasets/HumanResourceAnalytics/HR_comma_sep.csv")
HR_left<-HR_comma_sep[HR_comma_sep$left==1,]

Answer (score 2):

The number of "monthly hours" is at a very different scale than the other two variables, thus is skewing the clustering. The difference in "hours worked" is dominating the differences in the other two variables.
Normalize each column by dividing by the mean, the range or finding the z-score.

Original Code:

```
library(readr)
HR_comma_sep <- read_csv("https://stluc.manta.uqcloud.net/mdatascience/public/datasets/HumanResourceAnalytics/HR_comma_sep.csv")
HR_left<-HR_comma_sep[HR_comma_sep$left==1,]

library("ggplot2") 
x_org<-cbind(HR_left$average_montly_hours,
         HR_left$satisfaction_level,
         HR_left$last_evaluation) 

kmfit<-kmeans(x_org, 3, nstart = 25) 
pairs(x_org,col= (kmfit$cluster),labels=c("Av. Mon. Hrs","Sat. Lvl","Last Eval."))
```

[image]

Repeating the calculation using scaled values:

```
x_scaled<-cbind(scale(HR_left$average_montly_hours),
                scale(HR_left$satisfaction_level),
                scale(HR_left$last_evaluation)) 
kmfit<-kmeans(x_scaled, 3) 
pairs(x_org,col= (kmfit$cluster),labels=c("Av. Mon. Hrs","Sat. Lvl","Last Eval."))
```

[image]

Using just the raw values, the clustering based on difference in the "monthly hours", The top plot shows 2 clusters (black and green) merged together and not clearly distinct.
After scaling the values and repeating the clustering, 3 clearly differentiated clusters are now clearly shown (bottom image).